# What is "Black tie optional" in Chinese

Tags: translation

I'm writing a wedding invitation in both Chinese and English.  In English, the dress code is "black tie optional", which means guests are given the option to either wear a tuxedo or a proper dark coloured suit.  What would the equivalent of this be in Chinese?

Candidates I have so far are

- 正裝
- 禮服

Neither seem to accurately capture the equivalent of "black tie optional".  Any other suggestions?  If it matters, this invite will mostly be sent to people in Hong Kong.

Comment: Will it be sent to both men and women?

Comment: 随意着黑领结.........

Comment: Yes, both men and women

Comment: I am afraid there is no short equivalent Chinese term.  You may need to say explicitly, e.g. "男賓客請穿著禮服或深色西裝, 女賓客請穿著晚禮服或短禮服."  Or you can be creative and put sth like "衣著規定: 輕鬆隆重".  The guests will then read the English version.  ~ lol ~

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I went with:

> 禮服或正裝

Comment: Could you share your reasoning as to why you chose this solution?